# How to denote verses of a poem in running text?

Tags: print-design, typography

I need to fit a certain amount of text onto one double page of a print document. The text has several poems in it which of course have verses. But because it would take up too much space I can't use line breaks to signify the end of a verse. 
Is there a common character used for denoting the end of a verse or something else I can do to show where the verses end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the **slash** is used between running lines of poetry or song lyrics. You can capitalize according to grammar or at the beginning of each line, as you prefer:

Song lyrics:

> There comes a time/when you heed a certain call/and the world must come together as one/There are people dying,/oh and it's time to lend a hand to life — /the greatest gift of all
>
> We are the world/We are the children/We are the ones who make a brighter day, so let's start giving/There's a choice we're makin',/We're savin' our own lives/It's true we make a brighter day, just you and me

Poetry:

> How can my muse want subject to invent/While thou dost breathe, that pour'st into my verse/Thine own sweet argument, too excellent/For every vulgar paper to rehearse?/O, give thyself the thanks if aught in me/Worthy perusal stand against thy sight,/For who's so dumb that cannot write to thee,/When thou thyself dost give invention light?/Be thou the tenth Muse, ten times more in worth/Than those old nine which rhymers invocate,/And he that calls on thee, let him bring forth/Eternal numbers to outlive long date./If my slight muse do please these curious days,/The pain be mine, but thine shall be the praise.

Comment: Maybe worth noting for the sake of completeness: Usually stanzas are separated with double slashes: "//", as this option is mostly for quoting poetry inline in a prose text. Here, though, where the issue is to save space, the 'hybrid' solution of your first example probably offers the best compromise with readability.

Comment: @OliverScholz I didn't know about the double slash! How interesting. I was just posting two separate stanzas; they don't follow one another in the song.